# Ruby on Rails - Zeus permanently "freezes" test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtualbox, zeus

It happens to me a lot of times.

Test environment goes into "waiting" state FOREVER and nothing happens.

I can't fix that by reloading zeus manually (this is annoying...), and after manual reboot everything is fine.

But isn't `zeus` job to reload application correctly?

Screenshot:

[image]

I am using `Virtualbox 4.2.12 r84890` and `Debian 7.0`

```
@maci ➜  ✗ cat /etc/debian_version 
wheezy/sid
@maci ➜  ✗ uname -a
Linux maciej-VirtualBox 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Zeus version: `0.13.3`

Comment: I have put up, and restarts until everything will be okay

Answer (score 1):

Killing the zeus processes manually (with `killall -9 ruby` for example) *should* work,

my guess is that DB setup actions from test_helper block each other from executing completely and hang indefinitely, I've had especially a lot of grief with this on Oracle and almost no grief with SQLite. Restarting the db backend may help,

PS, if after killing the zeus process your console where zeus was running goes wacky do a `stty sane`